# Optimise a Stored procedure in SQL? Facing Error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, query-performance

Can someone help me to optimise this SP as it takes more than 3 minutes to run and then it gives Timeout error. "Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding." I am a beginner and would like to optimise  the below SP because it takes forever to give results and it also gives timeout error. I tried putting indexing to temp tables but unsuccessful. Help !!!!

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetCompanyByCandidatetest
@USER_ID VARCHAR(50) = NULL
AS
BEGIN

          declare @statenew varchar(1000) = Null 
          declare @countnew varchar(1000) = Null
          declare @STRSQLNew varchar(max)
          declare @STRSQL4 varchar(max)

           declare  @state1 varchar(1000) = Null ,@ind varchar(1000) = Null,@Distinct varchar(1000) = Null,@Dist1 varchar(1000) = Null,
           @EQuit_ID varchar(1000) =  Null,@Degree_ID varchar(100) = Null,@Isguest varchar(100) = Null,@verified varchar(100) = Null,
           @keyword varchar(100) = Null,@workexperience varchar(100) = Null,@prefcity varchar(100) = Null,@addcity varchar(100) = Null,
           @Key_skill varchar(100) = Null,@CURRENT_DEPARTMENT varchar(100),@PREF_DEPARTMENT varchar(100),@CURRENT_DESIGNATION varchar(100),@PREF_DESIGNATION varchar(100),@indcurr varchar(100)

            select @Isguest = isnull(guest_login,0), @verified = isnull(VERIFIED,0) from mtb_frinds where user_id = @USER_ID
            select @statenew  = isnull(PREF_STATE,''),@state1 = isnull(ADD_STATE,''),@Distinct = isnull(PREF_DISTRICT,''),@Distinct1 = isnull(add_dist,''),
            @ind = isnull(PREF_INDUSTRY,''),@indcurr=isnull(CURRENT_INDUSTRY,'') ,@EQuit_ID = isnull(EQ_ID,'') ,@keyword=isnull(key_word,'') ,@workexperience=isnull(WORK_EXPYEARS,''),@CURRENT_DEPARTMENT=isnull(CURRENT_DEPARTMENT,''), @PREF_DEPARTMENT=isnull(PREF_DEPARTMENT,''),
            @prefcity=isnull(PREF_CITY,'') ,@addcity=ADD_CITY,@Key_skill=isnull(Key_skill,''),@CURRENT_DESIGNATION=isnull(CURRENT_DESIGNATION,''),@PREF_DESIGNATION=isnull(PREF_DESIGNATION,'')

            from mtb_frinds where USER_ID = @USER_ID 

if(@statenew!='' and @Key_skill !='' and @state1 !='' and @keyword !='' )

begin
        print   'ind' +@ind  
        print '@indcurr' +@indcurr
         print '@PREF_DEPARTMENT'+ @PREF_DEPARTMENT 
         print  '@CURRENT_DEPARTMENT'+@CURRENT_DEPARTMENT
        print '@keyword'+ @keyword

set @STRSQLNew='
select ej_id, EQ_ID, JOB_STATUS  ,job_desc,
active,  USER_ID, JOB_TITLE, CREATED_ON,
REQUIRED_MP, WORK_EXPYEARS, SALARY, IND_ID,
Key_skill,  STATE_ID, DIST_ID, LOCALITY_ID,
DEPT_ID,1 as Priority, EXPIRATION_DATE

  into #dummy from mtb_jobs Ek
'

IF @EQuit_ID IS NOT NULL AND @EQuit_ID != ''
    BEGIN
    print 1
        SET @STRSQLNew = @STRSQLNew + ' CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(EQ_ID,'','') AS A
            CROSS APPLY dbo.Split('''+@EQuit_ID+''','','') AS B'  

            set @STRSQL4 ='(((A.items = B.items) or  '
    END
    IF @keyword IS NOT NULL AND @keyword != ''
    BEGIN
    print 2
        SET @STRSQLNew = @STRSQLNew + ' CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(keywords,'','') AS e
            CROSS APPLY dbo.Split('''+@keyword+''','','') AS f'  

            set @STRSQL4 =@STRSQL4+'(e.items =f.items)) and '
    END
    IF @statenew IS NOT NULL AND @statenew != ''
    BEGIN
    print 3
        SET @STRSQLNew = @STRSQLNew + ' CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(STATE_ID,'','') AS i
            CROSS APPLY dbo.Split('''+@statenew+''','','') AS j'  

            set @STRSQL4 = @STRSQL4+'((i.items =j.items) '
    END   
    IF @state1 IS NOT NULL AND @state1 != ''
    BEGIN
    print 4
        SET @STRSQLNew = @STRSQLNew + ' CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(STATE_ID,'','') AS k
            CROSS APPLY dbo.Split('''+@state1+''','','') AS l'  

            set @STRSQL4 =@STRSQL4+' or (k.items =l.items)) and '
    END
    IF @Key_skill IS NOT NULL AND @Key_skill != ''
    BEGIN
    print 5
        SET @STRSQLNew = @STRSQLNew + ' CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(Key_skill,'','') AS g
            CROSS APPLY dbo.Split('''+@Key_skill+''','','') AS h'               
            set @STRSQL4 =@STRSQL4+' ((g.items =h.items) or 
        '
    END
            set @STRSQLNew = @STRSQLNew+ ' where '+ @STRSQL4 +'(DEPT_ID in (select items from dbo.split('''+@CURRENT_DEPARTMENT+''','','')) or DEPT_ID in (select items from dbo.split('''+@PREF_DEPARTMENT+''','','')))))
            or(e.items =f.items and ((k.items =l.items) or (i.items =j.items) ))
            '
            set @STRSQLNew =@STRSQLNew+ ' select * into #temp from ( select   max(ej_id) as ej_id , max(EQ_ID) as EQ_ID, max(JOB_STATUS) as JOB_STATUS , max(job_desc) as job_desc,max(active) as active, max(USER_ID) as USER_ID ,max(JOB_TITLE) as JOB_TITLE ,max(CREATED_ON) as CREATED_ON ,max(REQUIRED_MP) as REQUIRED_MP ,max(WORK_EXPYEARS) as WORK_EXPYEARS ,
     max(SALARY) as SALARY ,max(IND_ID) as IND_ID ,max(Key_skill) as Key_skill  , max(STATE_ID) as STATE_ID ,max(DIST_ID) as DIST_ID,max(LOCALITY_ID) as LOCALITY_ID ,max(DEPT_ID) as DEPT_ID,2 as Priority,max(EXPIRATION_DATE) as EXPIRATION_DATE  from #dummy  where EXPIRATION_DATE >0 group by ej_id
            ) as x '
            set @STRSQLNew =@STRSQLNew+' select * into #Temp2 from
         (
         select  a.ej_id, isnull(a.JOB_TITLE,'''') as JOB_TITLE, isnull(b.ENT_NAME,'''') as ENT_NAME, CASE 
                WHEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, a.CREATED_ON, GETDATE()) < 60 THEN ''Just Posted'' 
                WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, a.CREATED_ON, GETDATE()) < 60 THEN CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, a.CREATED_ON, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(10)) + '' Minutes ago''
                WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, a.CREATED_ON, GETDATE()) < 24 * 60 THEN CAST(FLOOR(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, a.CREATED_ON, GETDATE())/60) AS VARCHAR(10)) + '' Hours ago''
                ELSE CAST(FLOOR(DATEDIFF(HOUR, a.CREATED_ON, GETDATE())/24) AS VARCHAR(10)) + ''Days ago''
            END AS POSTED_ON,a.REQUIRED_MP,''1'' as Issuitable,a.job_desc,  a.created_on,DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(),a.EXPIRATION_DATE) as EXPIRATION_DATE
            ,isnull('''+@Isguest+''',''0'') as Isguest,isnull('''+@verified+''',''0'') as Isverified
                ,isnull(cnt,0) as Isapplied,substring(
              (
                 Select distinct '', ''+ ST1.StateName  AS [text()]
                 From MTB_STATESNEW ST1
                 Where ST1.StateId in (select items from dbo.split (a.state_id,'',''))
                 For XML PATH ('''')
               ), 2, 1000000) [StateName],

                substring(
              (
                 Select distinct '', ''+ min(convert(varchar(1000),ST1.MIN_EXP))  AS [text()]
                 From dbo.MTB_WORKEXP ST1
                 Where ST1.EXP_ID in (select items from dbo.split (a.WORK_EXPYEARS,'',''))
                 For XML PATH ('''')
               ), 2, 1000000) [min_exp],
                substring(
              (
                 Select distinct '',''+ max(convert(varchar(1000),ST1.MAX_EXP))   AS [text()]
                 From dbo.MTB_WORKEXP ST1
                 Where ST1.EXP_ID in (select items from dbo.split (a.WORK_EXPYEARS,'',''))
                 For XML PATH ('''')
               ), 2, 1000000) [max_exp],
                  substring(
              (
                 Select distinct '', ''+ min(convert(varchar(1000),ST1.SR_MIN))   AS [text()]
                 From dbo.MTB_SALARYRANGE ST1
                 Where ST1.SR_ID in (select min(items) from dbo.split (a.SALARY,'',''))
                 For XML PATH ('''')
               ), 2, 1000000) [min_Salary],
                substring(
              (
                 Select distinct '',''+ max(convert(varchar(1000),ST1.sr_max))  AS [text()]
                 From dbo.MTB_SALARYRANGE ST1
                 Where ST1.SR_ID in (select items from dbo.split (a.SALARY,'',''))
                 For XML PATH ('''')
               ), 2, 1000000) [max_Salary],
               substring(
              (
                 Select distinct '',''+ (convert(varchar(1000),ST1.KEY_SKILL))  AS [text()]
                 From MTB_KEYSKILL ST1
                 Where ST1.KEYSKILL_ID in (select items from dbo.split (a.Key_skill,'',''))
                 For XML PATH ('''')
               ), 2, 1000000) [KEY_SKILL]
               ,
               substring (

                (Select distinct '',''+ (convert(varchar(1000),ST1.KEYWORDS))  AS [text()]
                 From mtb_keywords ST1 where st1.KEYWORD_ID in ( select items from dbo.split('''+@keyword+''','',''))
                  For XML PATH ('''')
               ), 2, 1000000) [KEY_Word],

               substring (

                (Select distinct '',''+ (convert(varchar(1000),ST1.DIST_NAME))  AS [text()]
                 From MTB_DISTSNEW ST1 where st1.DIST_ID in ( select items from dbo.split(a.DIST_ID,'',''))
                  For XML PATH ('''')
               ), 2, 1000000) [dist_name],

                substring(

               (select   distinct '',''+(convert(varchar(1000),ST1.EQ_NAME)) as [text()]
                from MTB_EDUQUALIFICATIONS ST1 where st1.EQ_ID in (select items from dbo.split(a.EQ_ID,'',''))
                For XML PATH('''')
               ),2,1000000) [EQ_Name],

                substring(

               (select   distinct '',''+(convert(varchar(1000),ST1.IND_NAME)) as [text()]
                from mtb_industry ST1 where st1.ind_id in (select items from dbo.split(a.ind_id,'',''))
                For XML PATH('''')
               ),2,1000000) [IND_NAME]                 
               from #temp as a inner join MTB_ENTERPRISES as b on a.user_id = b.user_id
                left join (select count (ej_id) as cnt,ej_id from TTB_JOBAPPLICATIONS where USER_ID = '''+@USER_ID+''' group by EJ_ID) as ER on ER.EJ_ID = a.EJ_ID
                where( a.JOB_STATUS = 1 and a.active = 1 )
                 ) as x'
            set @STRSQLNew =@STRSQLNew+' SELECT *,isnull(min_exp,'''') +''-''+ isnull(max_exp,'''') as WORK_EXP,isnull(min_Salary,'''') +''-''+ isnull(max_salary,'''') as Salary FROM #Temp2 '
            print @STRSQLNew
            exec (@STRSQLNew) 
            select 1 as ispara1, 'Sucess' as Msg  ,1 as n   
    end     

            else

            begin
            select top 0* from MTB_ENTERPRISES
            select 0 as ispara2, 0 as n,'Some fields are Incomplete' as Msg
            end
END
```

Error:- Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Comment: Are you getting timeout while executing from ssms or from your web/windows application?

Comment: From web. I tried increasing the timeout from web.config file. Still its giving same issue. The SP takes alot of time to run so before the operation finishes it gives timeout error. @Atk

Comment: It is not done in web.config. You need to explicitly set timeout in your code.

Comment: Can you help me optimise the SP. I feel because of SP only its giving that error

Comment: Some SP takes time to execute(even more than 5 minutes) and it all depends on the operations that are getting performed. Just by looking at the SP without knowing the table sructures, it is difficult to optimize. I can just help you in getting rid of timeout issue.

Comment: Can you give me an example for timeout. My project is built on ASP.NET MVC. On internet I searched it shows to increase the timeout in web.config. Any other way.

Comment: How are you calling this SP? can you show your code?

Comment: We are using dapper. Nd we have made a Repository class where we have opened sql connection and are calling that SP and storing the data in list (viewmodel)

Comment: It would be helpful if you show that code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209821/discussion-between-ankita-and-atk).